# Can't bake a proper normal map in Blender 2.9

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm trying to follow Andrew Price's anvil tutorial but I'm completely stuck at the point where he bakes the normal map from a high-poly sculpted mesh to a basic mesh...

I have tried changing the ray distance and extrusion, I've also tried to <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> the low-poly mesh and use it as a cage, but no matter what I do, the best normal map I get looks like this.

[image]

Most of it is blue-ish/purple, so the color scheme is matching a "proper" normal map, however it still looks really weird once I apply this image as a normal input to the low-poly mesh material. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your map looks normal, maybe the problem is your node setup, for example don't forget to switch your Image Texture from sRGB to Non-Color. If it's not your problem, please show a screenshot or share your file (pack the images before saving and uploading): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Wow, thanks for a fast reply! I'm trying to figure out how to compress my Blend file, since it's currently more than 50 MB. Thanks for the tip about packing the images. Made the file even bigger, but at least they are included now :D

Comment: please share the link  ;)

Comment: Here is the link to Google Drive!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zU8Go5jjExATc6ycEyr81Rzt7zwSZ0yu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new image in order to bake the normals, enable *32-Bit Float*:

[image]

Also, use another material for the high-poly object, otherwise the normal map will cumulate with the real bumps.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I've created a new image with 32-bit float enabled, that didn't change the result at all. Changed the material of the high-poly mesh as well, didn't change the result, but helps visually :) With the normal map that I get, some parts of the mesh look perfect, some other parts are completely unaffected, and some parts have weird artefact, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnNrt.png

The normal map itself also looks strange, if I zoom-in on it:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YlCF.png

I feel like something is wrong with the normal map itself...

Comment: It works here, maybe make sure that the Image Texture is set to Non-Color instead of sRGB, and push the Normal Map strength value to see if it gives something, because it's rather discrete

Comment: My image texture is non-color, and I've just tried pushing the Normal Map strength all the way to 10, it just makes the same weird artefacts more pronounced... Does your baked texture look the same as mine? Cause to me it looks like my mesh is getting exactly the baked texture, including the weird parts...

Comment: please share your file but pack your image, there was no packed image in the file you shared and I had to bake again. There seemed to be some bake bugs in 8.3, maybe first 2.9 versions, maybe it's your problem? In that case try with the latest versions or with 2.79

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zU8Go5jjExATc6ycEyr81Rzt7zwSZ0yu/view?usp=sharing
Does it work now? I got a notification "Some images have been painted on, these changes will not be saved". No idea what it means, I did not knowingly paint on anything...

Comment: plug the Image Texture into the Normal Map, it works fine: https://zupimages.net/up/21/15/z86c.jpg

Comment: Yeah, that part of the mesh does work fine, however other parts of the mesh - do not. Like the front part, where the circular cut-out is. It has a strange line going through it (in the image that I attached to one of the previous comments). I feel that the problem is in my UV-unwrapping of the low-poly model, since the artefacts seem to appear at the parts of the mesh where 2 layers of the UV-map are intersecting

Comment: UVs should not overlap of course, if the unwrap is bad, add some seams, or simply use the Smart UV Project mode (you should not need seams here)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's it... I do need seams according to BlenderGuru :D Smart UV Project gives me a seam at quite a visible place. Thanks for all the help! Going to fix my UVs and see if it works

Comment: I don't see any reason to use seams here but I may miss something, but you can solve it this way I guess: https://zupimages.net/up/21/15/vbx3.jpg

Comment: I've added several new seams and it starts looking better! At least the weird lines and other artefacts are gone. However, low-poly mesh with the applied normal map still looks very different from my high-poly mesh. E.g., in this spot, this is the high-poly mesh
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQE3i.png


And this is how the low-poly mesh with the normal map looks like at the same spot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1jxp.png

I'm trying to change the Extrusion , but it doesn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: make sure to not use the normal map on the high poly because it will increase the 3D effect. Also, normals may not look exactly like the baked object, it's just a trick to fake 3D, so it has its limitations

Comment: I've made a completely new material for the high-poly, so it doesn't have any normal map. The new problems seem to appear only around the seams - normal map is just not applied where a seam is and the low-poly model is visible. While in the other places it seems fine... Does normal-map not work properly around the seams?

Comment: it may bug a bit around the angles, maybe try to keep the bake "Extrusion" value as low as possible. Sometimes normal map are not perfect and you need to give it some corrections, for example you can paint some parts, etc

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I'll keep playing around with it. It's good to know it will not look EXACTLY like the high-poly mesh